# What's the longest time that a thread, which is blocking on receiving from an RS232 serial port, can take to wake up?

Tags: linux, serial-port, interrupt, blocking, latency

Assuming I set the process to the highest possible priority and there is no swap...

What's the longest time that a thread, which is blocking on receiving from an RS232 serial port, can take to wake up?

I want to know whether the thread will be woken within microseconds of the UART interrupt hitting the kernel, or whether it will have to wait for the next 100ms timeslice on a CPU.

Comment: Your question is poorly constructed.  It's the serial terminal driver that suspends and would unblock the process, not the UART driver.  Canonical versus noncanonical mode is a factor.  The process could block forever waiting for an EOL.  *"UART interrupt hitting the kernel"* is a poor reference considering interrupt generation and processing can be deferred.  The end of frame (i.e. the stop bit) on the wire is a better reference point.  *"whether it will have to wait for the next 100ms timeslice..."* -- No, the highest-priority runable  process gets control after a syscall completes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment (I'm only familiar with serial interfaces on ATMEGA and STM32 microcontrollers, hence my poor use of terminology).  If you write the last two lines of your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: What can defer interrupt generation and processing?  Can it be turned off, or sped up?  (I'm looking to minimise Linux serial latency between the received stop bit and the start bit of the reply from a high-priority userspace thread.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the longest time that a thread, which is blocking on receiving from an RS232 serial port, can take to wake up?

Depending on the mode (e.g. canonical) a process could wait forever (e.g. for the EOL character).

---

> I want to know whether the thread will be woken within microseconds of the UART interrupt hitting the kernel, or

The end of frame (i.e. the stop bit) on the wire is a better (i.e. consistent) reference point.

"*UART interrupt hitting the kernel*" is a poor reference point considering interrupt generation and processing can be deferred.
A UART FIFO may not generate an interrupt for every character/byte.
The interrupt controller prioritizes pending interrupts, and UARTs are rarely assigned high priorities.
Software can disable interrupts for critical regions.

---

> whether it will have to wait for the next 100ms timeslice on a CPU.

The highest-priority runable process gets control after a syscall completes.
Reference: [Linux Kernel Development: Preemption and Context Switching](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101760&seqNum=3):

```
Consequently, whenever the kernel is preparing to return to user-space, either 
on return from an interrupt or after a system call, the value of need_resched 
is checked. If it is set, the scheduler is invoked to select a new (more fit) 
process to execute.
```

---

> I'm looking to minimise Linux serial latency between the received stop bit and the start bit of the reply from a high-priority userspace thread.

I suspected that is what you are really seeking.
Configuration of the serial terminal is crucial for minimizing such latency, e.g. research the **ASYNC_LOW_LATENCY** serial flag.
However configuration of the Linux kernel can further improve/minimize such latency, e.g. [this developer reports](https://www.at91.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=21497&p=38871#p38871) a magnitude reduction from millisecs to only ~100 microsec.

---

> I'm only familiar with serial interfaces on ATMEGA and STM32 microcontrollers ...

Then be sure to review Linux [serial drivers](http://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/serial/serial.html).