# serial port: control, predict or at least optimize read() latency

Tags: linux, serial-port, modbus

I am designing application running on ARM9 working through serial port using Modbus. You may know that Modbus protocol is based on timing.

Originally I open port in non-blocking mode and use polling through `read()`. Then I learned, while it seems to work, it is not best, or even not a good solution for this environment. I have seen my thread execution "holes" of up to 60 ms (yes, milliseconds), and it is too much. I do not know if my measurements are correct - this is what I see on the screen, and it is not actually a question here.

I have learned there're a number of ways doing "high level" reading differently:

1. use another way of polling, e.g. epoll `epoll_wait`;
2. open serial port in blocking mode, and, in another thread, measure the time while `read()` is waiting for the data (e.g. timer somehow connected to the signal).

However, as I was told, the nature of Linux by default is not real-time, and nothing is guaranteed.

I am looking for advice and information if there're any hacks to design `read()` getting characters received from UART through all the software layers as quick as possible. Controlled delays up to 1ms would be acceptable (9600 baud).

For example, if I write code in specific way, compiler and target CPU will arrange timing in the way if it sees code loops waiting for some condition, CPU will turn away to another threads, but as soon as this thread's condition is met (no idea how - interrupt? watcher?) it switches to this thread as soon as it can and proceeds with it.

Comment: Your persistence in pursuing a userspace solution is futile.  Again, study [Linux serial drivers](http://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/serial/serial.html) to grasp that byte timing is destroyed by the buffering during receive processing.  If you can't have a timer in the driver's ISR, then this cannot be done accurately in software.  If you insist on pounding sand, then try using **ASYNC_LOW_LATENCY**, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61226450/whats-the-longest-time-that-a-thread-which-is-blocking-on-receiving-from-an-rs/61260098#61260098

Comment: @sawdust thank you very much for the information. Persistence is related to understanding that I either achieve it using software, or have to handle Modbus I/O using separate dedicated hardware. Hardware way is the best way, but it was not planned and creates cost and logistics. Therefore at least for this release I must find acceptable workaround through software, possibly without writing custom driver and using existing tuning mechanisms.

Comment: With a relatively slow baudrate of 9600, you might be able to crudely detect an inter-message idle-line interval of about the 3.5 character-times (i.e. 3.6 ms) that must precede a new Modbus message.  But that assumes a well-configured kernel similar to the Atmel developer that got receive latency down to ~100usec.  Latency was measured with a 'scope from the stop bit (of the last byte) on the wire to return from a non-canonical, blocking **read()** (and then flipping a GPIO).

Comment: And you also have to be able to measure the (abnormal) end of a Modbus message (i.e. a 1.5 character gap).  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62352322/does-modbus-rtu-require-a-gap-between-characters-when-transmitting/62354210#62354210

Comment: Beware that simply measuring the time interval between reads (instead of using timers) is flawed.  You risk a "rotting packet" scenario whenever the first byte of the "next" message is delayed.